# Unity определение угла между 2мя векторами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу узнать как вычислить угол между 2мя точками мыши:
`mousePos.x, mousePos.y`
Хотелось бы как узнать как это реализовать в 2 вариантах, полный угол 360 градусов и 180 градусов, в зависимости от того, в какую сторону повёрнут персонаж.
Прикрепляю наскальную живопись для лучшего понимания и код.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Crosshair : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject CrossHair;
public float Dir = 5f;

void Update () 
{
MoveCrossHair();
}

void MoveCrossHair(){
Vector3 point = new Vector3();
var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x,  mousePos.y, Dir));
if (point.magnitude > 0.0f)
{
    CrossHair.transform.position = point;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Что значит "между точками x и y"? Вы понимаете, что это компоненты одной точки? Почему у вас z компонента для позиции мыши равна 5? Это осознанное значение? Это важно для перспективной камеры.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker на сколько я понимаю, x и y это горизонталь и вертикаль, и между ними как-то можно вычислить угол, только не до конца понимаю каким образом. Z компонента меняется из скрипта управления персонажем в зависимости от определенных условий. Возможно, стоит вычислять угол между персонажем и мышью, но опять же не понимаю как это можно реализовать. По этому и задал вопрос, что мы меня подтолкнули в размышлениях.

Comment: Чего Вы хотите добиться, цель какая? (попытка уйти от `XY problem`)

Comment: @MBo Что бы отображался угол, в зависимости от того, где находится мышь относительно центра (персонажа).

Comment: Позиция мыши - это точка, вы можете представить вертикаль и горизонталь, используя компоненты этой точки (их пересечением и будет эта точка), но такие прямые перпендикулярны, а значит угол между ними всегда 90. **Скорее всего**, вы хотите найти угол между вектором mousepos и локальной для персонажа осью x.

Comment: В прошлом вопросе я вам уже написал - без базовых знаний векторной алгебры вы далеко не уйдете, раз вы не понимаете, что такое точка в пространстве. Можете не слушать меня - ваше право.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Вот, собственно я и осваиваю это в процессе, изменил изображение, чего я хочу добиться. Что бы при определенной позиции мыши от персонажа отображался определенный угол.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Угол направления от персонажа на мышь (т.е. угол между направлением оси OX и вектором person->mouse) в градусах можно найти так:

```
 float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y - person.y, mousePos.x - person.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

Для отображения диапазона 360 градусов потребуется исправлять отрицательные углы, добавляя +360 (если в юнити эта функция, как в большинстве языков, возвращает диапазон `-Pi..Pi`)